# What should I do in order to move to the United States?

Tags: usa, visa, relocation, italian-citizens

I have a really generic question and nobody has given me a satisfactory answer: let's say I live in Italy and one day I wake up and I want to move to the USA permanently, what are the legal steps to move in terms of visa, work, housing... Is my question even feasible or just pure fantasy?

Comment: Whoever downvotes, leave an explanation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In very broad terms, you can (these steps take many years):

- Get an [H-1B visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-1B_visa) with a job in the US
- Get a [green card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_residence_%28United_States%29) after completing a lot of paperwork such as labor certification
- (optional) Apply for US citizenship after holding your green card for some years

There are other ways such as the [Diversity Immigrant Visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_Immigrant_Visa) (also informally known as the "green card lottery").

Comment: There are many more visa possibilities depending on circumstances then just H-1.

Comment: You can become adopted by an American citizen. You can fall in love with and marry an American citizen. You can enroll in an American school and get a student visa.

Comment: @DouglasHeld I think adoption only works if you're under 18.